# ScrollLeft returns to the the set position, sadly not working on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, scroll

```
function scrollX(){
    bodyWidthDif = 1100-parseFloat($('html').width());
    bodyScroll = $('#top').scrollLeft();
       if (bodyWidthDif > 0){
            //#top is ID of BODY style element <BODY id="top">
           $('#top').css({"overflow":"scroll","max-width":"1100px"});
           if(bodyScroll > bodyWidthDif){
               $('#top').scrollLeft(bodyWidthDif);
           };       
       }else{
            $('#top').css({"overflow-x":"hidden"});
       }
};
$(window).scroll(function() {
    scrollX();
});
```

I have a problem with the code shown above, it's not working properly in FireFox but working on IE10, Opera, Safari and Chrome. Code is designed to reduce the possibility of scrolling left to 1100px on screens with resolution lower than 1100px;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem already solved.

```
function scrollX(){
bodyScroll = $('body').scrollLeft(); //var for Opera Chrome and Safar
htmlScroll = $('html').scrollLeft(); //var for Firefox
if(htmlScroll >= bodyWidthDif){
    $('html').scrollLeft(bodyWidthDif);
};
if(bodyScroll >= bodyWidthDif){
    $('body').scrollLeft(bodyWidthDif);
};
};
```

But I took advantage of another solution - simple using CSS.

```
<body style="overflow: visible">
    <div style="overflow: hidden; width: 1100px; height: 2000px; position: absolute;">
    </div>
</body>
```